# data source with count condition

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I've a data source which contains count in it. For some reason it fails with the following error.

**code**

```
data "oci_core_vcn" "test_vcn" {
    #Required
    vcn_id = oci_core_vcn.test_vcn.id
}


resource "oci_core_subnet" "test_subnet" {
    count = data.oci_core_vcn.default.id = "something" ? 1 : 0

    cidr_block = var.subnet_cidr_block
    compartment_id = var.compartment_id
    vcn_id = oci_core_vcn.test_vcn.id
}


count = data.oci_core_vcn.default.id = "something" ? 1 : 0

The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined   
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.   
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the   
resources that the count depends on.
```

Does anyone have any insights on  why it's failing?

Comment: It might help if you include the block for `resource "oci_core_vcn" "test_vcn"` that `vcn_id = oci_core_vcn.test_vcn.id` is referring to.

Comment: Ir's failing because it can't determine the result and hence the `count` meta-parameter. You could in theory try with `locals`, e.g., set `locals { something = data.oci_core_vcn.default.id = "something" ? 1 : 0 }`. Then, just use the local variable in count, e.g., `count = local.something == "something" ? 1 : 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question includes an example with a reference to a `resource "oci_core_vcn" "test_vcn"` block that you didn't include in your source code, but I think your use of that is part of the problem here.

As the error message explains, Terraform requires that the `count` expression be decidable based only on information available during the planning step, because otherwise Terraform cannot describe how many instances of that resource will be created.

Terraform will resolve data sources during the planning step *when possible*, but your `data "oci_core_vcn" "test_vcn"` block includes a reference to `oci_core_vcn.test_vcn.id` and so it would only be possible to resolve that data source once the `id` attribute is known, and most providers cannot predict `id` during the planning step because in many APIs the IDs of objects are assigned dynamically by the remote server during the create step, and that won't happen until the apply stage.

I also want to note that the data source you declared here seems redundant: you already have `oci_core_vcn.test_vcn` in this configuration and so there's little reason to retrieve the same object again using a data source, unless for this provider in particular there are some additional attributes of the data source that aren't available on the managed resource of the same name (which is possible, but would be unusual).

With the information given I cannot suggest an alternative way to achieve this result. The general problem here is that you will need to decide on a different condition to use to decide how many of `resource "oci_core_subnet" "test_subnet"` to declare, so that the decision depends only on information that Terraform can know during the planning step. If you're not sure, it could help to ask a new question on Stack Overflow that [describes the underlying problem you are trying to solve, rather than asking a question about a particular solution you tried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); I don't think the solution you've tried here is a viable one.